# Singular vectors/null states in algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)_{-4/3}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, conformal-field-theory

I encounter recently admissible affine Lie algebras when visiting some physics problems. I am reading Adamovic's [A construction of admissible $A_1^{(1)}$-modules of level $−4/3$](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401023).

In section 3, it is claimed that there is a unique maximal ideal generated by a singular vector (here I translated to the $J^\pm, J^3$ basis, $T$ is the stress tensor/Virasoro element, and $(..)$ means normal-ordered product)
$$
v^+_\text{sing} = (J^+ T) + \frac{1}{6} \partial^2 J^+ - (J^3 \partial J^+) + (\partial J^3 J^+) \ .
$$

By direct computation, I also observe that

- there are two more vectors $v_\text{sing}^3, v_\text{sing}^-$, that together with $v^+_\text{sing}$ form an $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ triplet.
- All three vectors comes from a next level state ($K$ being the Killing form)
  $$
  \chi = (TT)
  - \frac{1}{4} K_{ab}(\partial^2 J^a J^b) - \frac{3}{4}K_{ab}(\partial J^a \partial J^b) \ ,
  $$
  by $v^a_\text{sing} = J^a_1 \chi$.

My question is:

Given the relation with the singular vectors, should one expect $\chi$ to lead to vanishing torus one-point function (along the line of [Gaberdiel and Keller - Modular differential equations and null vectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0489)),
$$
\operatorname{tr} o(\chi) q^{L_0 - c/24} b^{J^3_0} = 0?
$$

(By direct application of Zhu's recursion formula, it seems it does. For example, when $b = 1$, it gives the equation (see [Arakawa and Kawasetsu - Quasi-lisse vertex algebras and modular linear differential equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.05865))
$$
(D_q^{(2)} - 15E_4) \operatorname{ch}_0 = 0 \ .
$$
But I don't know how to understand in the framework of [Gaberdiel and Keller - Modular differential equations and null vectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0489).)

Comment: For such an advanced question, I would be surprised if you could get help on this forum. It might be better to directly email (one of) the authors of the cited works.